# Has it ever been stated that One Piece is some kind of material treasure?

Tags: one-piece

Whitebeard said that when "the one" Gol D. Roger has been waiting shows up, he'll find the One Piece and he will turn the whole world upside down. I can't recall any statement that declares that One Piece is some kind of a treasure like gold or something.

It is just said that it is Gol D. Roger's treasure which he left in that place. So I wonder if it has ever been stated that One Piece is something tangible or something theoretical, something virtual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oda himself confirmed in an interview with Momoko Sakura that the One Piece isn't something like "the journey itself was the real treasure" and that it is, in fact, a **physical reward**.

There is confirmation that the treasure will not be a spiritual gift.

> **Oda**:"Yes, I already decided on how it's going to end. Should I tell you now?"
>
> **Sakura**:" .... Well, I want to know, but I probably shouldn't. BUT, the One Piece, it's not something like "the growth your heart went through", right?"
>
> **Oda**:"Hahaha, no no, I won't be pulling off some kind of Wizard of Oz thing like that. After having gone through an adventure like that, it wouldn't be fair to not actually give them a reward."

source: [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece)

**This link contains details that are spoiler in nature. Please click at your own risk**: [Interview details + Spoilers](http://www.kdramastars.com/articles/76949/20150305/one-piece-ending-spoilers.htm)

Comment: The reference that wikia use to claim that's a physical is the one you quote. Hasn't he said what kind of reward One Piece is clearly?

Comment: No he hasn't. That would kind of defeat the purpose of the "mysterious aura" behind the treasure. All that's been about the treasure is what has been stated above.